# Excel VBA - Intersect only specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro to check if a user selects a range within column "M". However, if the user selects a range in columns "M:N" for example, this bypasses the check. I would like to prevent that, so that users only select a range within column M (and not any other columns), before proceeding.

```
Set rngMyRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set srng = x_bf.Range(table[ColumnM])

If Intersect(rngMyRange, srng) Is Nothing Then
errline = "Please select a range in Column M only."
GoTo errhandler
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general pointer. Count the number of cells selected and the number in the intersection with M.

```
Sub x()

If Intersect(Selection, Range("M:M")).Count < Selection.Count Then
    MsgBox "outside col M selected"
Else
    MsgBox "only col M selected"
End If

End Sub
```